# Not able to call another module in requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

In below code I'm calling `myscript.getNum();` but `myscript.js` throws an error saying

> Unexpected Token (

**jloader.js**

```
require(["evtManager","myscript"] , function(evtManager , myscript) {

var el = document.getElementById("Clickarea");
evtManager.addEvent(el , "click" , function(){
    myscript.getNum();
    }); 
});
```

**myscript.js** ->loads `myscript2.js` and calls a function `getValue()`

```
define(["myscript2"], function(myscript2) 
{
    getNum : function(){            //Throws an error "Unexpected token (" 
        var x = require("myscript2").getValue();
        return 5 + x;
    }
});
```

**myscript2.js**

```
define({
    getValue : function(){
         return 30;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want **myscript.js** to return an object similar to this [example](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#defdep). I don't believe you need to require "myscript2" as that has already been done for you:

```
define(["myscript2"], function(myscript2)
{
    return {
        getNum : function(){
            var x = myscript2.getValue();
            return 5 + x;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply CgodLEY this is what i needed. Also can we have different functions within the script(myscript.js) like getName() , getAddress() , etc how can i achieve this ?

Comment: I'm not positive I understand your question, but you can certainly add other functions to the object you're returning. For example: `return { getNum : function(){return something;}, getName : function(){return somethingElse;}};`. Essentially you are using [JSON syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp) to assign functions to properties of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Your example, the important part:

function() {
    getNum : function(){
    }
}

How is that supposed to work? The colon is actually totally wrong there. You have to use an equal sign. You can either use `var getNum = function()` for a private method, or `this.getNum = function()` for a public method.